# How can I create a software RAID mirror of the system drive after installing Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit?

Tags: windows-8.1, gpt, raid-1

I have a brand new system with UEFI Install of Win 8.1 Pro 64 Bit.

The OS is installed on a 1TB WD Drive
I also have a second 1TB WD drive that is empty alongside it.

They both are GPT.  I'm having problems creating a mirror.  The options do not come up for recovery and efi partitions.  How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to build a RAID-1 out of 2 disks?  This involves enabling RAID within UEFI and installing Windows with the required drivers.  All I see is an unallocated physical secondary disk.

Comment: Software RAID using window's mirror drive abilities.  While I'm still interested in a solution to this, I have decided to use the motherboard's raid controller to accomplish my goals.

Comment: Note that few motherboards have true hardware RAID controllers; mostly they've just got software hooks to help out software RAID solutions in OSes. This type of RAID is tricky to configure to work in a cross-platform way. If you truly need cross-platform RAID, I strongly recommend buying a hardware RAID controller. They're often pricey, but easier to set up and less likely to cause problems than software RAID.

Answer (score -1):

First, you must manually copy EFI partition to the second disk with Diskpart.exe and Bcdedit.exe utilities.
Also EFI partition can not be mirrored.
After completed this step you can "Add mirror" of other part of your "Disk 0" to "Disk 1" with "Disk Management"

Step by step instruction how can you do that is here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951985

Also, you have similar instruction in this book:
InsideOUT - Windows Server 2012 R2 Configuration, Storage, & Essentials - William R. Stanek, Microsoft Press 2014
at 525. page in topic: "Mirroring boot and system volumes on GPT disks"

Comment: Edit your answer so you explain the entire process in the body of the answer itself.  Answers that only contain links are not that helpful.